# Перегрузка операторов для перечислений

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Можно ли перегружать операторы для типа перечисления `enum`? Если да, то как?

Не нашел запрета, но реализовать не получилось.

Я хочу взять и сделать, например, так:

```
Mode t = UP; t++; /*или*/ t+=2;
```

Comment: не очень понятен перегружать операторы для типа перечисления enum. поподробнее пожалуйста.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator я хочу взять и сделать например так: Mode t = UP; t++; //или  t +=1; Для этого нужно перегрузить оператор, как это сделать? Если можно

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно. Обычно делают так:

```
enum class Mode {
    UP,
    DOWN
};

// Префиксный инкремент.
Mode& operator++(Mode& m) {
    m = static_cast<Mode>(static_cast<int>(m) + 1);
    return m;
}

// Постфиксный инкремент.
Mode operator++(Mode& m, int) {
    Mode old = m;
    m = static_cast<Mode>(static_cast<int>(m) + 1);
    return old;
}

// Сложение.
Mode operator+(const Mode m, const int i) {
    return static_cast<Mode>(static_cast<int>(m) + i);
}
Mode operator+(const int i, const Mode m) {
    return operator+(m, i);
}

// Вычитание.
Mode operator-(const Mode m, const int i) {
    return static_cast<Mode>(static_cast<int>(m) - i);
}
Mode operator-(const int i, const Mode m) {
    return operator-(m, i);
}

// Сложение с присваиванием.
Mode& operator+=(Mode& m, int i) {
    m = operator+(m, i);
    return m;
}

// Вычитание с присваиванием.
Mode& operator-=(Mode& m, int i) {
    m = operator-(m, i);
    return m;
}
```

Если используется не `enum class`, а обычный `enum`, то внутренний `static_cast` можно убрать.

Comment: Прекрасно [работает](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L2invsSQoZq7G1G4) и с `enum class`. Ещё бы точку с запятой добавить.

Comment: А! Точно! `static_cast` сожрёт и `enum class`.

Comment: в вашем примере `static_cast` в скобках не нужен, и вы перегрузили префикс (++m), а требуется постфикс (m++)

Comment: @ampawd Без внутреннего `static_cast` не будет работать с `enum class`.

Comment: `Унарный префиксный инкремент`. А бывает бинарный? :)

Comment: @alexolut Верное замечание. Поправил.

Comment: Осталось ещё проверку диапазона прикрутить и можно в продакшн :-D

Comment: @alexolut Ну должно же хоть что-то автору вопроса остаться. ;-)